# Report viewer toolbar icons spaced too widely

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, report-viewer2010

First time adding a reporting services report into an ASP.NET page, and am using local processing.  Is there a way to control the reportviewer toolbar (Visual Studio 10) so that the icons aren't spaced so wide?  Mine were spanning multiple rows, and I could only get them onto one row by removing some of them.  Below is an image as well as the page code.

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptWireReport" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
    Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" 
    SizeToReportContent="true" ShowFindControls="False" 
    ShowZoomControl="False">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="reports\WireReport.rdlc">
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you look in [browser specific developer tools] to see what CSS rules are being applied to those icons?

Comment: Great thought.  I had some padding set on table cells, and this control happens to use table cells.  Problem solved.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help point you in the right direction.  You can answer your own question with the solution, or just delete it since there are no answers.  Good luck!

Comment: Second @jadarnel27, either of you should really put that as an answer as it might help future visitors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the reportviewer toolbar icons are using table cells for their layout, any padding or spacing applied to any of the table tags in CSS will have an affect on the layout of the toolbar.  In this case I was simply able to remove the unnecessary cellpadding values from the CSS so they would lay out correctly.